# javax.script.ScriptEngine Console extension or library?

Tags: java, scriptengine

With this I have added the console.log functionality to the javax.script.ScriptEngine.

```
   public class Console {
        public void log(String text){
            System.out.println("console: " + text);
        }
    }

    private static ScriptEngine getJavaScriptEngine(){
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");

    Console console = new Console();
    engine.put("console", console);

    return engine;
     }
```

As console and alert etc. are not part of the implementation. After a lot of searching I only found here and eleswhere only the same statement but wondering if there is not a library which does this right ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar solution, but found that it would not format objects / arrays. Nor that it would handle multiple arguments (e.g. `console.log('this is the answer:', 42)`).

To work around this, I had to polyfill `console`. It doesn't support all of its functions, but it will do for the purpose of logging. To format objects and arrays as JSON, it appeared that the `JSON` object wasn't available too - so had to polyfill that object too.

There is probably a prettier solution to this, but this setup got me going:

1. Polyfill the `JSON` object, take the script mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON#Polyfill. Rhino doesn't know about `window`, so replace:

   ```
   if (!window.JSON) {
     window.JSON = {
       // ... rest of code ...
     };
   }
   ```

   by:

   ```
   // if (!window.JSON) {
     // window.
     JSON = {
       // ... rest of code ...
     };
   // }
   ```

   Save it under `src/main/resources/scripts/json.js`.
2. Then, for the `console` object, put the following content in `src/main/resources/scripts/console.js`:

   ```
   console = {
     _format: function(values) {
       var msg = [];
       for (var i=0;i<values.length;i++)
         msg.push(JSON.stringify(values[i]));
       return msg.join(', ');
     },
     log: function() {
       log.fine(console._format(arguments));
     },
     info: function() {
       log.info(console._format(arguments));
     },
     warn: function() {
       log.warning(console._format(arguments));
     }
   };
   ```

   Note that this `console` implementation uses a `log` global variable. In my case, this is a JUL Logger instance, but with a little bit of creativity it can be changed to use another logging framework (e.g. SLF4j).
3. Finally, to put this all together in Java code, it can be done like this:

   ```
   public class ConsoleTest {

       public static void main(String... args) throws ScriptException, IOException {
           ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
           ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

           engine.put("log", Logger.getLogger("script"));
           run(engine, "/scripts/json.js");
           run(engine, "/scripts/console.js");

           engine.eval("console.log('string value');");
           engine.eval("console.warn(['array','value']);");
           engine.eval("console.info({a:1,b:'two'});");
       }

       private void run(ScriptEngine engine, String resourceName) throws ScriptException, IOException {
           InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
           Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
           engine.eval(reader);
           reader.close();
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: that looks pretty far, thanks for sharing it ! However I whish the JVM would help here in a new version maybe 1.9....